# Why these characters are all equal in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I just don't get it. See this SQL query:

```
select nchar(65217) -- ﻁ
select nchar(65218) -- ﻂ
select nchar(65219) -- ﻃ
select nchar(65220) -- ﻄ
if nchar(65217) = nchar(65218)
    print 'equal'
if nchar(65217) = nchar(65219)
    print 'equal'
if nchar(65217) = nchar(65220)
    print 'equal'
```

Based on [transitive relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), it means that SQL Server considers them all to be the same character.

However, in other environments, say for example C#, they're not the same.

What I'm confused about is:

1. How string comparison works in SQL Server
2. Why comparison doesn't behave the same on one machine, and one platform, but different environments
3. These 4 characters represent **one** human-understandable character. Why they are so abundant in Unicode character map?

This of course results in tremendous problems, because I'm working on a text-processing application and data comes almost from everywhere and I need to normalize text before processing it.

If I know the reason of difference, I might find a solution to handle it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All character data in SQL Server is associated with a collation, which determines the domain of characters that can be stored as well as the rules used to compare and sort data.  Collation applies to both Unicode and Non-Unicode data.

SQL Server includes 3 broad categories of collations: binary, legacy, and Windows. Collations in the binary category (`_BIN` suffix) use the underlying code points to compare so equality comparisons return not-equal if the code points differ regardless of the character.  Legacy (`SQL_` prefix) and Windows collations provide sorting and comparison semantics for the more natural dictionary rules.  This allows comparisons to consider case, accents, width, and Kana.  Windows collations provide more robust `word-sort` rules that closely align with the Windows OS whereas legacy collations consider only single characters.

The example below illustrates the differences between Windows and binary collation with the Teth character:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WindowsColationExample
    (
      Character1 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AS_SC
    , Character2 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AS_SC
    , Character3 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AS_SC
    , Character4 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AS_SC
    );

CREATE TABLE dbo.BinaryColationExample
    (
      Character1 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_BIN
    , Character2 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_BIN
    , Character3 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_BIN
    , Character4 nchar(1) COLLATE Arabic_100_BIN
    );

INSERT  INTO dbo.BinaryColationExample
VALUES  ( NCHAR(65217), NCHAR(65218), NCHAR(65219), NCHAR(65220) );
INSERT  INTO dbo.WindowsColationExample
VALUES  ( NCHAR(65217), NCHAR(65218), NCHAR(65219), NCHAR(65220) );

--all characters compare not equal
SELECT *
FROM dbo.BinaryColationExample
WHERE
    character1 = character2
    OR character1 = character3
    OR character1 = character4
    OR character2 = character3
    OR character2 = character4
    OR character3 = character4;

--all characters compare equal
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WindowsColationExample
WHERE character1 = character2;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WindowsColationExample
WHERE character1 = character3;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WindowsColationExample
WHERE character1 = character4;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WindowsColationExample
WHERE character2 = character3;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WindowsColationExample
WHERE character2 = character4;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WindowsColationExample
WHERE character3 = character4;
```

Reasons as to why Unicode may contain different code points for identical glyphs are outlined in  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_characters_in_Unicode.  I summary, it may be for legacy compatibility or the characters are not canonically equivalent.  Note that the Teth character `ﻁ` is used in different languages (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teth).

Answer (score 15):

This has something to do with the `COLLATION` of your database ([more information in BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx)).

I'm not entirely sure of the language of the specific character you're having a problem with (I'm guessing Persian based on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/1630de68-d7ef-4781-827f-0eb87d605db8/problem-search-in-sql-collation-persian) thread), but if you specify the correct collation in the equality operator, then you get accurate results.

```
if nchar(65217) COLLATE Persian_100_BIN = nchar(65218) COLLATE Persian_100_BIN 
    print 'equal'; -- nothing returned
if nchar(65217)  COLLATE Persian_100_BIN  = nchar(65217)  COLLATE Persian_100_BIN 
    print 'equal'; -- prints 'equal'
if nchar(65217) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = nchar(65220) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
    print 'equal'; -- prints 'equal'
```